# how do I force one of each type of child in an XSD?

Tags: xsd

I have two types of address, both of which need to be present and are both nested in a parent.  Is there a way that I can force one of each address type without redefining all the fields twice?

```
 <xs:element name="addresses">
    <xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="address" maxOccurs="2" minOccurs="2"> <!-- MUST BE ONE OF EACH ADDRESS TYPE - Invoice AND Delivery -->
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element type="xs:string" name="addresstype">
              <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                  <xs:enumeration value="I"/>
                  <xs:enumeration value="D"/>
                </xs:restriction>
              </xs:simpleType>
          </xs:element>
          <xs:element type="xs:string" name="addresscode"/>
          <xs:element type="xs:string" name="name"/>
          <xs:element type="xs:string" name="line1"/>
          <xs:element type="xs:string" name="line2"/>
          <xs:element type="xs:string" name="line3"/>
          <xs:element type="xs:string" name="line4"/>
          <xs:element type="xs:string" name="line5"/>
          <xs:element type="xs:string" name="postcode"/>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This requirement is not possible to achieve with XSD! I don't think it is possible even by defining all the fields twice! Because if you try to define parent `<address>` twice, I guess it will end up showing error, "an element can have only one (complex or simple) type"!